# como dar estilo diferente con CSS usando una misma clase pero en entornos diferentes

Tags: html, css

Tengo el siguiente codigo **HTML**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><!-- no-cache -->
<html>

<head>
<title>Ficha de Inventarios</title>
</head>

<body><!--sii.load head -->
    <link href="/js/utils_jqu.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/js/metro/sinfonix.css" rel="stylesheet">

<style>
 .title {
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:25px;
} 
</style>


<body onload="onLoad()" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">

 <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3" width="100%">
  <tr>
   <td nowrap width="1"
    ><a href='javascript:writeDocument("Nuevo","OFF","");'
    ><img border="0" name="m11" src="/images/metro_file_new.png"     title="Nuevo Documento"   ></a></td>
   <td nowrap width="1"
    ><a href='javascript:writeDocument("Acepta","OFF","");'
    ><img border="0" name="m12" src="/images/metro_file_write.png"   title="Guardar Documento"  ></a></td>
    <td nowrap width="1"
    ><a href='javascript:writeDocument("Elimina","OFF","");'
    ><img border="0" name="m20" src="/images/metro_file_delete.png"  title="Eliminar Documento" ></a></td>
   <td nowrap width="1"
    ><a href='javascript:verifidForm("myForm.reset()");'
    ><img border="0" name="m14" src="/images/metro_file_undo.png"         title="Deshacer Cambios"  ></a></td>
    <td nowrap width="1"
    ><a href='javascript:writeDocument("Acepta","PRINT","");'
    ><img border="0" name="m13" src="/images/metro_file_print.png"   title="Imprimir (Ctrl+P)" ></a></td>
    <td nowrap width="1"
    ><a href='javascript:writeDocument("Acepta","ON","");'
    ><img border="0" name="m23" src="/images/metro_file_preview.png" title="Formato Imprimible"></a></td>
   <td nowrap align="right"><a class="title" href="javascript:CallSQL('^CIA.sql','list','','LoadCompany','key%20codigo%20nombre');">Compañia de Prueba, S.A.&nbsp;&nbsp; </a></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
<script>
function writeDocument(button, preview) {
 if (myForm) {
  switch (preview) {
    case "PRINT":
      if (myForm.preview) {
        if (window.submit) {
          window.submit(button, preview);
        }
      } else {
        window.print();
      }

    default:
      window.submit(button, preview);
  }
 } else {
  window.parent.location.reload(true);
 }
}
</script>

<div id="main" style="position: relative; visibility: hidden; width:100%">

 <form action="/cgi-bin/sinfonix.pl?AD-0354464104726F6F7403323535023937%20IN630.www" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm" target="connect9">
  <div align="center">
   <table class="Main">
    <tr>
     <td>
      <table class="Head" width="100%">
       <tr>
        <td valign="bottom">
         <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5">
     <tr>
      <td nowrap valign="top">Código de Producto<br>
       <input size="20" maxlength="20" name="codigo" value="" onchange="javascript:CallSQLproducto('record');" class="search_IN630" 
       > <a href="javascript:CallSQLproducto('list');"
       ><img src="/images/search_list.png" title="Selecciona el Producto de una Lista" align="absmiddle" border="0"></a></td>
      <td>Línea de Ventas<br>
       <select name="LineaVenta" size="1">
       <option></option>
<option value="30303031">DUROTEST - ILUMINACION LARGA N</option>
<option value="39313030">CONSUMIBLES</option>
<option value="39393939">CONSUMIBLES SERVICIO TECNICO</option></select></td>
     </tr>
    </table></td>
    <td align="center"><span class="title">FICHA DE INVENTARIO</span><br>
    <a class="font-normal" href="javascript:CallSQL('^INV.sql','list','','LoadInvent','key%20codigo%20nombre');">
    (MERCANCIA PARA LA VENTA)</a></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  <table class="Body" id="Body">
   <tr>
    <td valign="top"><span class="title">Datos Básicos</span>
    <table border="0" cellspacing="5">
     <tr>
      <td valign="top" nowrap align="center"
                        ><img id="foto"  src="/cgi-bin/sinfonix_image.pl?AD-0354464104726F6F7403323535023937%20^IMAGE.www%20647F616836273123212D3B317F3D2C25262C3E6E32362B2D6829263C2C223D22.jpg" align="absbottom" border="0" style="width:82 height:82" width="82" height="82" data-file="#file_image">&nbsp;</td>
      <td valign="top" nowrap align="center"
                        >
    <table border="0" cellspacing="5">
     <tr>
      <td>
      Descripción</td>
      <td style="width:330px">
        <input type="text" size="30" maxlength="30" name="Descripcion" value="" style="width: 100%"></td>
      <td style="width:50px">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
      Existencia Mínima</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" size="13" name="ExistMinima" value="" style="text-align: right; width: 240px" maxlength="9"> </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Descripcion 2</td>
        <td><input type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" name="refer_data_1" value="" style="width:100%"></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Existencia Máxima</td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" size="13" name="ExistMaxima" value="" style="text-align: right; width: 240px" maxlength="9"> </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>No.de Parte</td>
        <td><input type="text" size="20" maxlength="20" name="refer_data_2" value="" style="width:100%"></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Cantidad a Pedir</td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" size="13" name="CantPedir" value="" style="text-align: right; width: 240px" maxlength="9"> </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Descripcion US</td>
        <td><input type="text" size="30" maxlength="30" name="refer_data_3" value="" style="width:100%"></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Catalogo y Pagina</td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" size="5" name="Catalogo" value="" style="text-align: right; width: 117px" maxlength="2">
        <input type="text" size="7" name="Pagina" value="" style="text-align: right; width: 116px" maxlength="4"> </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Descripcion US2</td>
        <td><input type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" name="refer_data_4" value="" style="width:100%"></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Referencia</td>
        <td><select name="refer_data_5" size="1" style="width:100%"><option></option>
<option value="31">TABLA 1</option>
<option value="32">TABLA 2</option></select></td>
     </tr>
    </table></td>
     </tr>
     </table></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
    <div id="tabs-content" class="tabs-resizer" style="padding:5px; width:989px; height:419px">
     <div id="tabs">
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#Precios">Listas de Precios y Unidades de Medidas</a></li>
<!--sii.if 1 -->
                     <li><a href="#Proveedores">Modelos de los Proveedores</a></li>
<!--sii.fi -->
<!--sii.if 1 -->
                     <li><a href="#Adicionales">Datos Adicionales</a></li>
<!--sii.fi -->
                  </ul>
      <div id="Precios" style="padding:0px" align="center">
       <table class="Body" width="100%" height="100%">
        <tr>
         <td valign="top"><span class="title">Listas de Precios</span><div align="center">
          <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
           <tr>
            <th class="LN" nowrap>Descripción</th>
<!--sii.for 5 -->
                              <th class="LN" nowrap colspan="2">PRECIO 1</th>

<!--1   next -->
                              <th class="LN" nowrap colspan="2">PRECIO 2</th>

<!--2   next -->
                              <th class="LN" nowrap colspan="2">PRECIO 3</th>

<!--3   next -->
                              <th class="LN" nowrap colspan="2">PRECIO 4</th>

<!--4   next -->
                              <th class="LN" nowrap colspan="2">PRECIO 5</th>

<!--5   next -->
                            </tr>
           <tr>
            <td nowrap align="right">Precio de Venta&nbsp;</td>
<!--sii.for 5 -->
                              <td nowrap align="right" colspan="2">
            <input type="text" size="12" name="Pventa_Valor1" value="" maxlength="13"  style="text-align: right;width:95px"></td>
<!--1   next -->
                              <td nowrap align="right" colspan="2">
            <input type="text" size="12" name="Pventa_Valor2" value="" maxlength="13"  style="text-align: right;width:95px"></td>
<!--2   next -->
                              <td nowrap align="right" colspan="2">
            <input type="text" size="12" name="Pventa_Valor3" value="" maxlength="13"  style="text-align: right;width:95px"></td>
<!--3   next -->
                              <td nowrap align="right" colspan="2">
            <input type="text" size="12" name="Pventa_Valor4" value="" maxlength="13"  style="text-align: right;width:95px"></td>
<!--4   next -->
                              <td nowrap align="right" colspan="2">
            <input type="text" size="12" name="Pventa_Valor5" value="" maxlength="13"  style="text-align: right;width:95px"></td>
<!--5   next -->
                            </tr>
           <tr>
            <td nowrap align="right">Comisión Base&nbsp;</td>
<!--sii.for 5 -->
                              <td nowrap align="left">
            <input type="text" size="1"  name="PVenta_CBF1"   value=""   maxlength="1"   style="text-align: right;width:10px" title="Formato de la Comision B=Bolivares, %=Porcentaje, T=Codigo de Tabla"></td>
            <td nowrap align="right">
            <input type="text" size="10" name="PVenta_CBM1"   value=""   maxlength="10"  style="text-align: right;width:81px" title="Valor Segun Formato"></td>
<!--1   next -->
                              <td nowrap align="left">
            <input type="text" size="1"  name="PVenta_CBF2"   value=""   maxlength="1"   style="text-align: right;width:10px" title="Formato de la Comision B=Bolivares, %=Porcentaje, T=Codigo de Tabla"></td>
            <td nowrap align="right">
            <input type="text" size="10" name="PVenta_CBM2"   value=""   maxlength="10"  style="text-align: right;width:81px" title="Valor Segun Formato"></td>
<!--2   next -->
                              <td nowrap align="left">
            <input type="text" size="1"  name="PVenta_CBF3"   value=""   maxlength="1"   style="text-align: right;width:10px" title="Formato de la Comision B=Bolivares, %=Porcentaje, T=Codigo de Tabla"></td>
            <td nowrap align="right">
            <input type="text" size="10" name="PVenta_CBM3"   value=""   maxlength="10"  style="text-align: right;width:81px" title="Valor Segun Formato"></td>
<!--3   next -->
                              <td nowrap align="left">
            <input type="text" size="1"  name="PVenta_CBF4"   value=""   maxlength="1"   style="text-align: right;width:10px" title="Formato de la Comision B=Bolivares, %=Porcentaje, T=Codigo de Tabla"></td>
            <td nowrap align="right">
            <input type="text" size="10" name="PVenta_CBM4"   value=""   maxlength="10"  style="text-align: right;width:81px" title="Valor Segun Formato"></td>
<!--4   next -->
                              <td nowrap align="left">
            <input type="text" size="1"  name="PVenta_CBF5"   value=""   maxlength="1"   style="text-align: right;width:10px" title="Formato de la Comision B=Bolivares, %=Porcentaje, T=Codigo de Tabla"></td>
            <td nowrap align="right">
            <input type="text" size="10" name="PVenta_CBM5"   value=""   maxlength="10"  style="text-align: right;width:81px" title="Valor Segun Formato"></td>
<!--5   next -->
                            </tr>
           <tr>
            <td nowrap align="right">Dscto.Máximo&nbsp;</td>
<!--sii.for 5 -->
                              <td nowrap align="left">
            <input type="text" size="1"  name="PVenta_DMF1"   value=""   maxlength="1"   style="text-align: right;width:10px" title="Formato del Descuento B=Bolivares, %=Porcentaje, T=Codigo de Tabla"></td>
            <td nowrap align="right">
            <input type="text" size="10" name="PVenta_DMM1"   value=""   maxlength="10"  style="text-align: right;width:81px" title="Valor Segun Formato"></td>
<!--1   next -->
                              <td nowrap align="left">
            <input type="text" size="1"  name="PVenta_DMF2"   value=""   maxlength="1"   style="text-align: right;width:10px" title="Formato del Descuento B=Bolivares, %=Porcentaje, T=Codigo de Tabla"></td>
            <td nowrap align="right">
            <input type="text" size="10" name="PVenta_DMM2"   value=""   maxlength="10"  style="text-align: right;width:81px" title="Valor Segun Formato"></td>
<!--2   next -->
                              <td nowrap align="left">
            <input type="text" size="1"  name="PVenta_DMF3"   value=""   maxlength="1"   style="text-align: right;width:10px" title="Formato del Descuento B=Bolivares, %=Porcentaje, T=Codigo de Tabla"></td>
            <td nowrap align="right">
            <input type="text" size="10" name="PVenta_DMM3"   value=""   maxlength="10"  style="text-align: right;width:81px" title="Valor Segun Formato"></td>
<!--3   next -->
                              <td nowrap align="left">
            <input type="text" size="1"  name="PVenta_DMF4"   value=""   maxlength="1"   style="text-align: right;width:10px" title="Formato del Descuento B=Bolivares, %=Porcentaje, T=Codigo de Tabla"></td>
            <td nowrap align="right">
            <input type="text" size="10" name="PVenta_DMM4"   value=""   maxlength="10"  style="text-align: right;width:81px" title="Valor Segun Formato"></td>
<!--4   next -->
                              <td nowrap align="left">
            <input type="text" size="1"  name="PVenta_DMF5"   value=""   maxlength="1"   style="text-align: right;width:10px" title="Formato del Descuento B=Bolivares, %=Porcentaje, T=Codigo de Tabla"></td>
            <td nowrap align="right">
            <input type="text" size="10" name="PVenta_DMM5"   value=""   maxlength="10"  style="text-align: right;width:81px" title="Valor Segun Formato"></td>
<!--5   next -->
                            </tr>
          </table></div></td>
         <td valign="top"><div align="center"><span class="title">Unidad de Medida</span>
          <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
           <tr>
            <th class="LN" nowrap>Codigo</th>
            <th class="LN" nowrap>Base de Calculo</th>
           </tr>
<!--sii.for 3 -->
                             <tr>
            <td align="center" nowrap>
            <select name="UND_codigo1" size="1">
            <option></option>
<option value="424C">BLOCK</option>
            </select></td>
            <td align="center" nowrap>
            <input type="text" size="13" name="UND_Base1" value="" style="text-align: right" maxlength="8" ></td>
           </tr>
<!--1   next -->
                             <tr>
            <td align="center" nowrap>
            <select name="UND_codigo2" size="1">
            <option></option>
<option value="424C">BLOCK</option>
            </select></td>
            <td align="center" nowrap>
            <input type="text" size="13" name="UND_Base2" value="" style="text-align: right" maxlength="8" ></td>
           </tr>
<!--2   next -->
                             <tr>
            <td align="center" nowrap>
            <select name="UND_codigo3" size="1">
            <option></option>
<option value="424C">BLOCK</option>
            </select></td>
            <td align="center" nowrap>
            <input type="text" size="13" name="UND_Base3" value="" style="text-align: right" maxlength="8" disabled></td>
           </tr>
<!--3   next -->
                           </table></div></td>
        </tr>
       </table></div>
<!--sii.if 1 -->
                 <div id="Proveedores" style="padding:0px" align="center">
       <table class="Body" width="100%" height="100%">
        <tr>
         <td valign="top"><span class="title">Proveedores</span>
         <div align="center"><center>
          <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
           <tr>
            <th class="LN" nowrap>Código</th>
            <th class="LN" nowrap>Nombre o Razón Social del Proveedor</th>
            <th class="LN" nowrap>Modelo</th>
           </tr>
<!--sii.for 7 -->
           <tr>
            <td nowrap>
            <input type="text" size="10" name="PROV_Codigo1" value="" onchange="javascript:LINE='1';CallSQL('CP630.sql','Record',this.value,'LoadProv','codigo nombre');" maxlength="8"></td>
            <td nowrap>
            <input type="text" size="50" name="PROV_Nombre1" value="" disabled></td>
            <td nowrap>
            <input type="text" size="22" name="PROV_Modelo1" value="" maxlength="20"></td>
           </tr>
<!--1   next -->
           <tr>
            <td nowrap>
            <input type="text" size="10" name="PROV_Codigo2" value="" onchange="javascript:LINE='2';CallSQL('CP630.sql','Record',this.value,'LoadProv','codigo nombre');" maxlength="8"></td>
            <td nowrap>
            <input type="text" size="50" name="PROV_Nombre2" value="" disabled></td>
            <td nowrap>
            <input type="text" size="22" name="PROV_Modelo2" value="" maxlength="20"></td>
           </tr>
<!--2   next -->
           <tr>
            <td nowrap>
            <input type="text" size="10" name="PROV_Codigo3" value="" onchange="javascript:LINE='3';CallSQL('CP630.sql','Record',this.value,'LoadProv','codigo nombre');" maxlength="8"></td>
            <td nowrap>
            <input type="text" size="50" name="PROV_Nombre3" value="" disabled></td>
            <td nowrap>
            <input type="text" size="22" name="PROV_Modelo3" value="" maxlength="20"></td>
           </tr>
<!--3   next -->
           <tr>
            <td nowrap>
            <input type="text" size="10" name="PROV_Codigo4" value="" onchange="javascript:LINE='4';CallSQL('CP630.sql','Record',this.value,'LoadProv','codigo nombre');" maxlength="8"></td>
            <td nowrap>
            <input type="text" size="50" name="PROV_Nombre4" value="" disabled></td>
            <td nowrap>
            <input type="text" size="22" name="PROV_Modelo4" value="" maxlength="20"></td>
           </tr>
<!--4   next -->
           <tr>
            <td nowrap>
            <input type="text" size="10" name="PROV_Codigo5" value="" onchange="javascript:LINE='5';CallSQL('CP630.sql','Record',this.value,'LoadProv','codigo nombre');" maxlength="8"></td>
            <td nowrap>
            <input type="text" size="50" name="PROV_Nombre5" value="" disabled></td>
            <td nowrap>
            <input type="text" size="22" name="PROV_Modelo5" value="" maxlength="20"></td>
           </tr>
<!--5   next -->
           <tr>
            <td nowrap>
            <input type="text" size="10" name="PROV_Codigo6" value="" onchange="javascript:LINE='6';CallSQL('CP630.sql','Record',this.value,'LoadProv','codigo nombre');" maxlength="8"></td>
            <td nowrap>
            <input type="text" size="50" name="PROV_Nombre6" value="" disabled></td>
            <td nowrap>
            <input type="text" size="22" name="PROV_Modelo6" value="" maxlength="20"></td>
           </tr>
<!--6   next -->
           <tr>
            <td nowrap>
            <input type="text" size="10" name="PROV_Codigo7" value="" onchange="javascript:LINE='7';CallSQL('CP630.sql','Record',this.value,'LoadProv','codigo nombre');" maxlength="8"></td>
            <td nowrap>
            <input type="text" size="50" name="PROV_Nombre7" value="" disabled></td>
            <td nowrap>
            <input type="text" size="22" name="PROV_Modelo7" value="" maxlength="20"></td>
           </tr>
<!--7   next -->
                               </table></center></div></td>
        </tr>
       </table></div>
<!--sii.fi -->
<!--sii.if 1 -->
                 <div id="Adicionales" style="padding:0px">
       <table class="Body" width="100%" height="100%">
        <tr>
         <td valign="top"><span class="title">Datos Adicionales</span>
         <div align="center"><center>
          <table border="0" cellspacing="5">
<!--sii.for 1 -->
                                <tr>
            <td>Numero de Parte     </td>
            <td><input type="text" size="3" maxlength="1" name="ref_data_1" value="" ></td>
           </tr>
<!--1   next -->
                              </table></center></div></td>
        </tr>
       </table></div>
<!--sii.fi -->
          </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div style="display:none;">
  <input type="hidden" name="button" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="config" value="00000009494E3633302E77777700000003000000">
  <input type="file" name="file_image"        id="file_image"        onchange="photoChange('#foto', event  );">
  <input type="text" name="file_image_delete" id="file_image_delete" onchange="photoChange('#foto','DELETE');">
</div>
</form><!--sii.load copyright -->
 </div>

 <iframe name="connect9" src="/html/licenced.txt" style="display:none"></iframe>
 <div class="loading_modal"></div>
</body>

<!-- jQuery core -->
<script src="../js/jquery/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Sinfonix core -->
<script src="../js/utils.js"></script>
<script src="../js/utils_jqu.js"></script>

<script src="../cgi-bin/sinfonix.js?AD-0354464104726F6F7403323535023937%20IN630.js"></script>

<script src="../js/jquery/plugin/popImg.js" defer="defer"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery/plugin/jquery.progress.js" defer="defer"></script>

<link  href="../js/jquery/plugin/jquery.modal.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="../js/jquery/plugin/jquery.modal.js" defer="defer"></script>

<!-- metro UI CSS 3.0 -->
<xlink  href="../js/demo/metro/docs/css/metro.css" rel="stylesheet">
<xscript src="../js/demo/metro/docs/js/metro.js" defer="defer"></script>

<!-- jQuery UI -->
<link  href="../js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="../js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js" defer="defer"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

El cual se puede resumir (para los efectos) de la siguiente manera:

```
<style>
 .title {
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:25px;
} 
</style>
...
...
...
   <td nowrap align="right"><a class="title" href="javascript:CallSQL('^CIA.sql','list','','LoadCompany','key%20codigo%20nombre');">Compañia de Prueba, S.A.&nbsp;&nbsp; </a></td>
  </tr>
...
...
...
 <td>
  <div id="tabs-content" class="tabs-resizer" style="padding:5px;    width:989px; height:419px">
   <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#Precios">Listas de Precios y Unidades de Medidas</a></li>
     <li><a href="#Proveedores">Modelos de los Proveedores</a></li>
     <li><a href="#Adicionales">Datos Adicionales</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="Precios" style="padding:0px" align="center">
     <table class="Body" width="100%" height="100%">
      <tr>
       <td valign="top"><span class="title">Listas de Precios</span><div align="center">
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
         <tr>
          <th class="LN" nowrap>Descripción</th>
          <th class="LN" nowrap colspan="2">PRECIO 1</th>
          <th class="LN" nowrap colspan="2">PRECIO 2</th>
...
...
...
```

Como verán tengo la clase `class="title"` la cual se caracteriza por dar un color blanco a la fuente, esta clase la utilizo en 2 partes diferentes del documento pero he aquí el problema: el fondo donde utilizo la primera clase es negro y el fondo donde utilizo la segunda clase es blanco, obviamente el contenido de la fuente no se nota con fondo blanco.

**Ahora mi pregunta es la siguiente:**
puedo yo hacer con **CSS** (sin modificar el código **HTML** pero si basándonos en su contenido), hacer que el color de la clase cambie?.

NOTA:
Puedo yo conjugar las clase "**title**" que esta dentro de otra clase para que se comporte diferente. (notese que en la segunda clase esta dentro de la clase "**tabs-resizer**").

Es decir, tengo esto:

```
<style>
 .title {
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:25px;
} 
</style>
```

y quiero esto:

```
<style>
 .title {
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:25px;

 .tab-resizer.title {
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#000;
  font-size:25px;
} 
</style>
```

Es esto posible?

Comment: Si accede primero al elemento HTML y después a su clase, `table tr td .title` `span .title` no creo que este sea el selector correcto, pero es lo que puedes hacer

Comment: @Lixus, aunque no muestro el contenido completo, el primer "**title**" también esta en una tabla por lo que sugieres no creo me resuelva, lo que si tengo es otra clase que es "**tabs-resizer**" sera que puedo conjugar estas 2 clases?

Comment: Ya te dejé una respuesta, igual y si quieres pon tu tabla completa para así ver si debo modificar el snippet para que se ajuste a tu tabla

Comment: intentare colocarla completa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si es posible lo que pensaba, lo que quería es lo siguiente:

```css
body {
  background-color:#000;
  color:#fff;
}
.title {
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:25px;
}
.tabs-resizer {
  background-color:#fff;
  color:#000;
}
.tabs-resizer .title {
  color:#000;
}
```

```html
<span class="title">Titulo de la pagina
</span>
<p>Contenido de la pagina</p>
<div class="tabs-resizer">
<span class="title">Titulo de las lineas
</span>
<p>lineas del documento</p>
<p>lineas del documento</p>
<p>lineas del documento</p>
</div>
<span class="title">Pie de pagina
</span>
```

Notese que **tabs-resizer** invierte **body** por tanto **tabs-resizer** conjugado con **title** (que si se puede) invierte el color de la fuente.

Answer (score 1):

Si se puede, solo tienes que agregar otra clase...

La clase `title` te da los estilos comunes y agrega una clase adicional para los estilos diferenciados.

En el ejemplo, ambas capas tienen el estilo `title` que hace que el texto salga en negritas y centrado. Pero uno de los elementos tiene una clase adicional que hace que el texto sea blanco y el fondo negro.

```css
.title {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.3em;
 }
 
 .tabs-resizer {
   margin-top: 30px;
   background-color: black;
   color: white;
 }
```

```html
<div class="title">Este es un título</div>

<div class="tabs-resizer">
  <div class="title">El título con fondo negro</div>
</div>
```

> #### Nota
>
> Se modifica el ejemplo, para ajustarse a las condiciones de la pregunta.

Comment: Este código lo tengo replicado en todo el proyecto por lo que es necesario hacerlo solo a través de **CSS**, No puedo modificar el código **HTML**.

Comment: Opino que es lo mismo, voy a modificar mi respuesta...

Comment: Estimado **@toledano**, gracias por tu pronto respuesta pero ya la clase existe y es **tabs-resizer**, entonces quisiera conjugar esta con **title** pero en un archivo que ya tengo donde están los estilos, sin modificar el código **HTML**

Comment: @fwBasic eso es exactamente lo que hice.

Comment: Ah caramba!!.. Disculpa... Lo probare! solo que no se ve como esperaba que fuese ;))...

Comment: una pregunta... y donde esta la conjugación? te explico **tabs-resizer** tiene un comportamiento que no puedo cambiar y **title** también tiene un comportamiento y solo este debe cambiar cuando este dentro de **tabs-resizer**.

Comment: Así está el ejemplo. El segundo title está dentro de tabnoseque. Tal vez no comprendo que es lo que quieres.

Answer (score 0):

Si puedes, solo debes de acceder primero al elemento HTML, en este caso `span` y `td` respectivamente, y después de eso modificas sus atributos de CSS.

Te dejo un ejemplo para que veas como:

```css
span.title{
  background-color: red;
}

a.title{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<span class='title'>Hola mundo</span>

<table>
<tr>
  <td><a href='' class='title'>HOla a todos</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Gracias @Lixus pero sera que eso lo puedo hacer con la clase "**title**" 
 + "**tabs-resizer**"? alguna manera de conjugarlas?